# How to query embed document in mongoDB by the key value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to search for all documents that have `255255` as their key value. the `id` on top is the id of the document.

```
"id" : "555114",
    "255255" : {
        "someField" : null,
    },
    "255256" : {
        "someField" : null,
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$exist` to check if the key is present in document or not.

```
db.yourCollection.find({"255255":{$exist:true}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [exists](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator.

From the MongoDB docs:

> Syntax: `{ field: { $exists: <boolean> } }`
>
> When `<boolean>` is true, `$exists` matches the documents that contain the field, including documents where the field value is null. If `<boolean>` is false, the query returns only the documents that do not contain the field

```
db.yourcollection.find({ 255255: { $exists: true } });
```

Answer (score -1):

To query embedded documents in MongoDB by the key value, you can use the dot notation to access the specific field within the embedded document. In your case, you want to search for all documents that have the key "255255" with the value you are looking for.
You can do this using the following query:

```
db.collectionName.find({
  "255255": { $eq: { "someField": null } }
})
```

Explanation:

db.collectionName: Replace collectionName with the actual name of your collection.
"255255": This is the key you want to query in the document.
{ $eq: { "someField": null } }: This is the condition you want to apply to the value of the key. In this case, it is checking if the field "someField" within the key "255255" is equal to null.
This query will return all documents in the collection where the key "255255" exists and its "someField" value is null.

If you are using a programming language to interact with MongoDB, such as JavaScript with Node.js, you can use the MongoDB driver to perform this query. Here's an example of how you can do it with Node.js:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

// Connection URL and database name
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'yourDatabaseName';

// Key to search for
const keyToSearch = '255255';

// Connect to MongoDB
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, client) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB:', err);
    return;
  }

  // Get the database
  const db = client.db(dbName);

  // Get the collection
  const collection = db.collection('yourCollectionName');

  // Query the documents with the given key and value
  collection.find({ [keyToSearch]: { $eq: { "someField": null } } }).toArray(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error executing query:', err);
      return;
    }

    console.log('Documents matching the query:');
    console.log(result);

    // Close the connection
    client.close();
  });
});
```